# Why Advent Vega keeps losing Wi-Fi?

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I recently bought a Advent Vega Android tablet and everything is working completely fine, however there is one slight problem with Wi-Fi.

Even though I have full Wi-Fi signal *(it is as high as it can be)*, and it has been happily working for a while, after some time the Wi-Fi disconnects and when I go into the Wi-Fi settings it states that the network is out off range. If I turn off the Wi-Fi and re-enable it, it works fine.

I've tried a couple of different ROMs but they all have the same problem. Does anyone have any clues as to how this can be fixed?

Comment: One thing to look out for is wifi sleep state (In your settings, under *Wifi*, select *Advanced* from the overflow menu. *Keep Wifi On During Sleep* should be set to Always).  If this is the case, the best you can do is try to get more info on the problem...

Comment: Besides ensuring that there are no obstacles between your Wifi router and your phone (walls, wireless phones, microwaves, other routers), you should also confirm that you see the same behaviour with various levels of Wifi security.  This is a common problem with certain hardeare and is something to confirm.

Comment: Check here [Modaco](http://www.modaco.com/forum/474-advent-vega-vegamodacocom) Looking through the threads, its seems a firmware problem, have you tried updating it?

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be that you have a wifi time out enabled? Check the wifi settings *carefully*. Also, make sure the wifi sleep setting is diabled.

It could of course be a hardware issue (and probably is if it happens on multiple roms). It could be that the wifi card in the tablet 'Shuts Off' after a certain time, check online as this would happen to all owners of the tablet if this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Android Tablet rejects the wifi connection once they recieve any corrupt packet.

To fix this issue we need to handle the exception at the network layer.

Install **[Wifi-Fixer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wahtod.wififixer)** App from Playstore. Then:

1. Run wifi from this app only.
2. You will be able to see the logs of the packets.
3. Issue will be solved automatically, if not revert back.